# create a list of strings using a foreach loop from list of doubles. every two values must be compressed into a single string then added to list

Tags: c#, string, loops, foreach

I hope someone has a good was of solving this problem.

So I have a list of doubles these being coordinates, example -123123, 12313. shown in image below.

[List of doubles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yaop.png)

these are being used in this foreach loop:

```
foreach (var coord in element.geometry.coordinates)
{


}
```

I'm trying to make a list of said coordinates - but instead of them being a list of single coordinates I need them to be compressed into two.

So rather than a list of

- -1213123
- 1345
- -345
- 1234535

I need a list of strings like so.

- -1213123, 1345
- -345, 1234535

using var 'coord' this being a single coordinate when coming out of the foreach loop. how can I create a list pairing every two values that come out of the loop.

Thanks for any help given :)

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<list.Count; i+=2)`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Could you please elaborate on that. What list is list.count referring to? and how would that turn a list of 600 into a list of 300 with values paired into strings?

Comment: Have you, perchance, made any attempt?

Answer (score 0):

if the foreach loop is compulsory, then

```
string[] lst = new string[element.geometry.coordinates.Count() / 2];

int i=0;
foreach (var coord in element.geometry.coordinates)
{
    if (i % 2 == 1) 
        lst[i-1] = $"{lst[i-1]}, coord";
    else
        lst[i] = coord

    ++i;

}
```

Comment: Any reason for downvoting?

Comment: Because posting answers to no-effort "gimme teh codez" questions doesn't help achieve Stack Overflow's stated objective of becoming a repository for **high-quality** questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

I know it looks a little bit weird, but you can you Linq.Zip method.

```
        var coordinates = element.geometry.coordinates;
        var result = coordinates
            .Where((_, index) => index % 2 == 0) // Get even numbers
            .Zip(
                coordinates.Where((_, index) => index % 2 == 1), // Get odd numbers
                (first, second) => $"{first}, {second}") // Zip them together
            .ToList(); // If you need the result as List<string>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot take a step other than 1 in a `foreach` loop. Therefore I propose to use a `for` loop instead. It can be set to step 2.

```
var doubles = new List<double> { -1213123, 1345, -345, 1234535 };
var strings = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < doubles.Count; i += 2)
{
    strings.Add(doubles[i] + ", " + doubles[i + 1]);
}
```

Do not need extra conditional `if` statements. This solution turns out to be as simple and effective as possible.